# Can the same @page directive be used on more than 1 'page' in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, directive

So a blazor page (Razor component) has @page "/mypage" at the top. Can I have it so more than one 'page' have the same directive? It doesn't seem so but thought I would ask to be sure.

Comment: What would you expect that to accomplish?

Comment: Because without understanding what you are trying to accomplish, it is difficult to provide you with a solution to any problem you might be having.

Comment: I want several different pages to always have the same 'url', if possible

Comment: But then which page is returned when you type the URL in the browser?  (I'm asking these leading questions, because in my opinion, this question doesn't make any sense)

Comment: they wouldn't be navigating by typing the URL, just from links and buttons within the pages

Comment: Right, but the point of a URL is that it can be entered into the browser.  Remember that that will always be possible, and it's an important concept to maintain in any SPA.  Put another way, if they aren't using the URL for navigation, why would you want all pages to share the same URL?  Users like to be able to bookmark pages and for that to have meaning.

Comment: It doesn't matter why, I have my reasons which you should just accept. But if it is not doable, then fine.

Comment: Do you mean add multiple routes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057524/blazor-webassembly-multiple-route-on-same-component-rendering)?If so,you can do like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't.  The server will throw an exception complaining that there are multiple razor components with the same address.

Answer (score 0):

The same @page directive cannot be used on multiple pages.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Here's Microsoft doc:

Components support multiple route templates using multiple @page directives. The following example component loads on requests for /blazor-route and /different-blazor-route.

```
@page "/blazor-route"
@page "/different-blazor-route"

<h1>Blazor routing</h1>
```

Note that you must also include the `<base>` tag in the index.html (inside wwwroot folder) for the URLs to resolve correctly. See link for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I think you read the question wrong.  Same page directive, multiple pages was the question. You answered multiple page directives on the same page.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, however it is not answering the question which was asked.  The person wanted to know if you could use the same @page directive on two different pages...

Comment: My bad. English is not my first language and sometimes I misread.